# Two regex pattern in to one

Tags: php, regex

Patterns is working fine but i want them in one regex patter:

```
$reg_data['phone']  = preg_replace('/[\s\(\)]+/', '', $reg_data['phone']);
$reg_data['phone']  = preg_replace('/^\+998/', '', $reg_data['phone']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [alternation operator `|`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

```
$reg_data['phone']  = preg_replace('~[\s\(\)]+|^\+998~', '', $reg_data['phone']);
```

Comment: Note that `^` complicates the matters, for example for `(+998)123` results will be different from the OP.

Comment: in my case +998 comes only in first (phone county code) but thanks @georg